Chroot on Linux server for user login
I have set up Debian chroot environment on my openSUSE server.
So, the regular users have a playground and can install packages without affecting the main system. It's for home use only so no one else should have access to it if nothing goes wrong.
My questions are:
I need some directories and files from the main system to use the same accounts.
My current setup is
ln -sf /etc/resolv.conf $CHROOT_DIR/etc/resolv.conf

and in fstab
# Bind mounts for chroot environment
/proc         /srv/chroot/debian/proc         proc   defaults   0   0
/dev          /srv/chroot/debian/dev          none   rbind   0   0
#/dev/pts      /srv/chroot/debian/dev/pts      none   bind   0   0
/sys          /srv/chroot/debian/sys          none   rbind   0   0
/etc/passwd   /srv/chroot/debian/etc/passwd   none   bind   0   0
/etc/group    /srv/chroot/debian/etc/group    none   bind   0   0
/etc/shadow   /srv/chroot/debian/etc/shadow   none   bind   0   0
/home         /srv/chroot/debian/home         none   bind   0   0
/var/mail     /srv/chroot/debian/var/mail     none   bind   0   0

for resolv.conf, /etc/passwd, group, shadow should I use symbolic links or mount binds?
What are the advantages and disadvantages and what makes more sense?
My other question is, I use x11-forwarding to start some gui applications in Windows with VcXsrv. Works so far but I always need export DISPLAY=IP_ADDRESS:0 first.
I could write it in .bashrc or .profile but that only works if the IP is the same and if I stay within the same network. If I connect form somewhere outside (Internet), it doesn't know what to do with the private IP. Interesting is, if I try it with a Linux PC, it works and also without the export.
here the sshd_config file.
# Global settings
PermitRootLogin yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes

Match User *,!root
        ChrootDirectory /srv/chroot/debian/
        AllowTCPForwarding yes
        X11Forwarding yes
        X11DisplayOffset 10
        X11UseLocalHost yes
#       PermitTTY no


Symbolic links won't work across the chroot.
If you do a
ln -sf /etc/resolv.conf $CHROOT_DIR/etc/resolv.conf

the resulting link may look OK when testing it non-chrooted, but any chrooted programs will end up looking a file whose true path (= as viewed outside the chroot) will be $CHROOT_DIR/$CHROOT_DIR/etc/resolv.conf which is not what you wanted.
A bind mount is the only option that will work correctly for both chrooted and non-chrooted processes.


I use x11-forwarding to start some gui applications in Windows with VcXsrv. Works so far but I always need export DISPLAY=IP_ADDRESS:0 first.

In StackExchange, you're supposed to ask just one question in each Question post. But since this is a security-sensitive issue:
If you run export DISPLAY=IP_ADDRESS:0 you are actually bypassing the X11-forwarding and falling back to old-school unencrypted X11 connections over the network. And since you apparently aren't even using Xauth cookies (setting them up with unencrypted remote X11 connections requires extra steps), anyone who can make a TCP connection to port 6000 of IP_ADDRESS will be able to monitor all your keystrokes and mouse events.
The individual X11 applications will make connections to the X11 display server (e.g. VcXsrv), so to be able to make unencrypted X11 connections over the internet, the X11 display server of your local system (= the one you are physically located at) would have to be accessible by a public IP address. This is an extremely bad idea; please do not do this. The tools to abuse such unprotected X11 connections have existed at least 25 years by now.
If you have a problem starting up a X11-forwarding connection on Windows, please make a separate question of it on SuperUser.SE.
